# How to inject "Type" via Unity XML configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've a class structure like following:

```
public class Processor : IRegister
{
  public Processor(IRequiredDependency dependency)
  {
  }

  public Type[] ObjectTypes { get; set; }
}

public class TextFile
{}

public class ImageFile
{}
```

We use design time unity configuration (XML based) for our application. I'd like to inject value for `ObjectTypes`. I've XML config like following:

```
      <type type="SomeNamespace.IRegister, SomeBinary"
            mapTo="SomeNamespace.Processor, SomeOtherBinary"
            name="MyProcessor">
        <property name="ObjectTypes">
          <array>
            <value value="SomeOtherNameSpace.TextFile, SomeOtherBinary"/>
            <value value="SomeOtherNameSpace.ImageFile, SomeOtherBinary"/>
          </array>
        </property>
      </type>
```

I was expecting that unity would be able to translate "`SomeOtherNameSpace.TextFile, SomeOtherBinary`" which is nothing but "`FullyQualifiedClassName, AssemblyName`". But I'm getting following error:

`TypeConverter` cannot convert from `System.String`.

Looks like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx) has helped me a bit. I was missing the typeConverter attribute in the `<value>`. The default type converter was unable to convert from `string` to `Type`. I had to write TypeConverter to support this.

The updated XML config now look like:

```
 <unity>
    <alias alias="MyTypeConverter" type="Namespace.MyTypeConverter, MyBinary" />
    <containers>
      <container>
type type="SomeNamespace.IRegister, SomeBinary"
            mapTo="SomeNamespace.Processor, SomeOtherBinary"
            name="MyProcessor">
        <property name="ObjectTypes">
          <array>
            <value value="SomeOtherNameSpace.TextFile, SomeOtherBinary" typeConveter="MyTypeConverter"/>
            <value value="SomeOtherNameSpace.ImageFile, SomeOtherBinary" typeConveter="MyTypeConverter"/>
          </array>
        </property>
      </type>
```

Note: I had to add TypeConverter implementation which is as simple as:

```
public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return Type.GetType(value.ToString());
    }
```